# React app not displaying map using openlayers

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

I am unable to integrate openlayers map in react app. I followed their tutorial but not sure where I went wrong. I also tried some youtube tutorials.

Can you experts help ?

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/simple.html

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import View from 'ol/View';

var map = new Map({
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(),
    }) ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2,
  }),
});

export default map;
```

I am importing this way :

```
 import "./Base.css"

function Base() {
    return (
      <div className = "map" id="map"/>
    );
  }
  
export default Base;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since `myMap` doesn't return and jsx component using `<myMap />` doesn't count as a use, hense you get that message. any way that message does't mean anything and if you implementation works don't bother.

Comment: Thank you! No it doesnt work also but I am trying to fix it. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

The examples for OpenLayers are not for React. This is how you create an OpenLayers map component in react:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj';


export default function Map() {
    const mapRef = useRef(null);
    const [map, setMap] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const initialMap = new Map({
            target: mapRef.current,
            layers: [
                new TileLayer({
                    source: new OSM(),
                }),
            ],
            view: new View({
                center: fromLonLat([0, 0]),
                zoom: 2,
            }),
        });
        setMap(initialMap);
        return () => initialMap.setTarget(null)
    }, []);

    return (
        <div
            ref={mapRef}
            style={{ width: '100%', height: '500px' }}
        />
    );
}
```

You can take a look at this [blog](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-incorporate-openlayers-maps-into-react-65b411985744) for a more comprehensive example.